# Locating an HTML button element without i.d or class name using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nunit

Web driver couldn't find the x icon (Close) I used XPath and Full XPath to locate the x icon. Here's my code so far:

```
       webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("*[@id='root']/div/div/div[1]/button")).Click();
```

I copied this `*[@id='root']/div/div/div[1]/button` by inspecting the element. The error displayed after running the automation testing is this:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9LJg.png)

I also tried to use Katalon Studio to check if I could get the XPath, it did generate the XPath, but, once I pasted it, it's not working as well.

Comment: It's a bit hard for anyone to provide you with an answer when we don't have the site or HMTL snippet of the DOM.

Comment: Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks

Comment: Found the solution, since I'm trying to locate an element within an Iframe, I have to find the IFrame first, then switch to that Iframe before I could locate the element that I'm looking for and for this case, that element I was looking for was the button with x icon.